# SwiftUI Firestore - How to Batch and Delay Local Document Updates for Cost Efficiency?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an iOS app using SwiftUI and Firestore. I have a use case where I want to make local changes to a Firestore document and read document form cache and then periodically synchronize those changes with the server to minimize the number of writes to Firestore and improve cost efficiency. Here's the workflow I'm trying to achieve:

Users make changes to a Firestore document within the app while offline (no network access).
These local changes are stored locally and not immediately synchronized with the Firestore server.
After a specific time interval (e.g., every X minutes), I want to batch and send all the accumulated local changes to the server as a single write operation, rather than writing each change individually.
I've looked into Firestore's offline data persistence, but it seems to synchronize changes immediately when the network is available, causing a separate write operation for each local change.

Is there a way in SwiftUI and Firestore to batch and delay local document updates and then send them to the server as a single write operation at specified intervals to optimize cost efficiency and reduce the number of writes to the server?

Any guidance or code examples on how to implement this delayed synchronization mechanism would be greatly appreciated.

```
func updateSubject(with color: String) {
            let path = "subjects.\(selectedSubject.name.rawValue).color"
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            
            if dateOfLastUpdate.isOneMinutePassedOrMore {
                // Re-enable the network when you're done with offline operations.
                performUpdateOperation()
                db.enableNetwork { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error enabling network: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        // Network is enabled again.
                        performUpdateOperation()
                    }
                }
                dateOfLastUpdate = Date()
            } else {
                db.disableNetwork { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error disabling network: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        // The network is now disabled.
                        performUpdateOperation()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            func performUpdateOperation() {
                db.collection(FirestoreCollection.student)
                     .document(studentId)
                    .updateData([path: color]) { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error updating subject color: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

I'm using Firestore with SwiftUI on iOS.
My main objective is to reduce the number of writes to the server and improve cost efficiency by batching and delaying local changes for synchronization with the Firestore server.

Comment: There is no SwiftUI here — this is just Swift.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data

Answer (score 0):

Create a single-instance object, perhaps a singleton, that manages all of this document's data. Whenever the user changes data through the UI, update this data-manager object, which simply updates its internal properties (nothing more). Because this object is a single-instance object, add a timer within it that updates the documents in a batch write every `n` seconds. The batch write is the ideal method to update the server because its offline capable, unlike the transaction (the other atomic server operation). However, if there is only a single document to update then simply update it as you normally would, since that operation is also offline-capable.

Finally, optimize this data object to additionally update the server perhaps before the app is terminated or before the app transitions into the background, so there isn't the possibility that this object is holding fresh data that never makes it to the server such as when the user places the app in the background and the app is later killed by the OS before it can reenter the foreground.